# Creating Paypal Donate Button

Tags: button, paypal, donations

I can't seem to find a way to create a Paypal Donate button.

[This Link](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) seems useful but it's actually useless.

I can only find these buttons :

- Shopping Card
- Buy Now
- Gift Certificates
- Subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Donation button is open to the limited countries. If you can't see the donation type in your options, which means donation button is not available to your country.